# Is it possible to use SFTP inside a GCP Cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, sftp, pysftp

I just need to pull some data from a SFTP server on a cron schedule in GCP. I was hoping to use a Cloud Function with the python SFTP library (pysftp) but I am not sure if this is possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it could be not possible if the used library depends on system package.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's expected that you make an attempt at solving the problem before posting.  If you have specific code that isn't working the way you expect, post that along with your debugging details.